# Arhitecture of Client Server communication with OAuth2 framework

Tags: architecture, oauth-2.0

I'm going to implement a following solution -

1. Server for my back-end logic with RESTful API and web portal with user dashboards.
2. Client application(dedicated per user) - consumer of this Server API.

I have to implement a following logic - User register at web portal from point #1. After login to his dashboard he receives a SECRET_KEY (access token). Right after that, user provides this SECRET_KEY to the settings of Client application from point #2. Client applications starts consume Server RESTful API in some way with this SECRET_KEY.

Now, what technologies I'm going to use in order to implement security model for current architecture - I think OAuth2 framework will work well here.

I'm going to introduce own OAuth2 server with my Server for back-end logic with RESTful API.

Right now I have a few questions:

Do I need to introduce dedicated OAuth2 `clientId` for an each registered user ?

What artifact from OAuth2 should be used as SECRET_KEY in order to provide it to RESTful API calls from client app to server? How to authorize client application based on this SECRET_KEY with no need to provide username/password there ?